# Vacation workflow - Multiple calendars based on approval

Tags: 2013

I have created a vacation approval workflow in sharepoint 2013. Basically user inputs information on vacation/sick time/etc into request. This then gets routed to their supervisor to review. If approved, the leave is then added to the department SP calendar. So here is my issue. I have a separate SP calendar for management only. What I want to do is add an entry on that calendar too. The management calendar will display the type of Leave it is where as the Department calendar will only show when an individual is off. I have everything working except for that second calendar entry. Any suggestion on how to handle this in the workflow ?

Comment: Would changing the view work for the different calendars? If you create a view for Management and then a view for Department.

Comment: Do you mean using the same calendar but just giving management more view rights to it? And not using 2 separate calendars ?

Comment: Yes - if this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the information you have given you have a calendar with a series of Choice selections - something like below:

- Vacation - Choice
- Sick - Choice
- Leave Overtime - Choice

Supervisor to reviews and approves.
Once event is approved it will show in the Department Calendar view shows the status of the staff member as Available or Not Available (whatever wording you prefer to use)
In the Management Calendar view all other details will show depending on the fields created and selected for that view will appear. 
You may want to look at the permission groups you have for your users.

Comment: I currently have 2 separate groups set up. The admin group can see their management calendar and the Department calendar. The rest of the Department, non admin, can only see the Department calendar. How do I change the views of each group ? Basically, how can I prevent the non admin group from viewing the leave details , sick leave or vacation or etc, on the same calendar that the admins can see? 1 calendar would be a lot easier than 2.

Comment: I looked at the user permissions. For the management group, they have edit rights. For the staff, I'm not sure which one to put them under. Read only ?

Comment: if you need to use both calendars and create a calendar overlay - these can be visible or not visible.  In the instance of the management calendar it will be out of view and only those with the correct permissions may see it - once again - suitable permissions for each calendar is required.

Comment: I have the 2 calendars set up. The management calendar can only be viewed by the management group. The Department calendar can be view by management and non management. Management group has edit rights. Non management has read only. My issue is that when I run the workflow, it will only add the event to the Department calendar. It won't add an entry to the Management calendar. Are workflows restricted from adding the same event into 2 separate calendars ?

Comment: Checked every permission setting I could. Ended up finding out this to be the issue. Thanks for the help.